# Powershell: Is there a way to add variables from an array to a file as strings?

Tags: arrays, powershell, lua

I'm attempting to fill in a .lua file with variables comprised of filenames in a "data" folder (the number of these files can vary).  For example, I have the following folder structure:

```
Object
  data
    file1.meta
    file2.meta
  stream
  *.lua file
```

I have written the following to get the objects out of the data folder:

```
$Path = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\object\data\' -Name '*.meta' -File
$Path.ForEach([string])
```

Which works wonderful.  I get the results as items in an array, again, exactly what I want.  I want to use these array items to "fill in the blanks" as individual variables to create the .lua file which will look like:

```
files 
{
    'data/file1.meta',
    'data/file2.meta',
}

data_file 'METADATA_FILE1' 'data/file1.meta'
data_file 'METADATA_FILE2' 'data/file2.meta'
```

I was able to hardcode this using $Path[0] and $Path[1] and so forth, but I can potentially have more/less files to add, and I need the exact number that the data folder contains each time...what I'm struggling with is to run a foreach loop the correct number of times and use the array items as output in the .lua file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a multi-line string with the file structure that you can use as a template:

```
$luaFileTemplate = @'
files 
{{
{0}
}}

{1}
'@
```

Now you can use `.ForEach()` and `-join` to create the content based on the file names:

```
$fileLines = $Path.ForEach({"    'data/$_',"}) -join [Environment]::Newline
$dataFileCount = 1
$dataFileLines = $files = $Path.ForEach({"data_file 'METADATA_FILE$(($dataFileCount++))' 'data/$_'"}) -join [Environment]::Newline
```

And then finally apply the values to the template string with the `-f` operator and write it to disk:

```
$luaFileContents = $luaFileTemplate -f $fileLines,$dataFileLines
$luaFileContents |Set-Content final_file.lua
```

Comment: Thank you!!  This was a huge help!

Comment: One thing I forgot to clarify, and it changes the syntax a bit, the "data_file" portion needs to be named similarly to what the .meta file is (i.e. if the meta file is objectproperties.meta, the data file needs to be OBJECT_META, similarly if it's colorproperties.meta, the data file needs to be COLOR_PROP_META, etc.  I imagine this can just be done with an if-statement block for each potential result?  There are only like 6-8 variations of what meta files the data folder can contain.

Comment: @Phydeaux86 Create a hashtable that maps `colorproperties` to `COLOR_PROP_META` etc., then replace `data_file` with something like `$($hashtable[$_ -replace '\.meta$'])`